# Exported function to pass arguments and a constant to another function

Tags: javascript

I don't really know how to describe this, but I'll try explain it.

I want to be able to call `func1()` and `func2()`, but going through `handler()` in a module.
I want it in a way where calling `module.exported1("foo")` will call `handler(func1, "foo")`, in turn calling `func1("foo")`. The issue I'm having is that if I export 'exported1' as `handler(func1)`, I can't pass any arguments exported1 was called with (As far as I know). Is there a workaround for this?

NOTE: It is a module, and I need it to be exported without the user needing to provide `func1` and `func2` to `handler()`.

```js
function func1(args) {
    ...
}
function func2(args) {
    ...
}

function handler(func, args) {
    return func()
}
module.exports = {
    exported1 = handler(func1, ...),
    exported2 = handler(func2, ...)
}
```

Comment: That should complain loudly about a syntax error?

Comment: Do you mean `function handler(func) { return function(args) { return func(args); }; }`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to export the function:

```
module.exports = {
    exported = handler
}
```

Or, just:

```
exports.exported = handler
```

Now, after import, you can call with parameters:

```
exported(func1,...)
exported(func2,...)
```

---

After reading your edited question, I think you want to do something like this but I'm not pretty sure:

```
function handler(func) {
    // you can replace it with function(args) { instead of arrow function
    return (args) => {
     return func(args)
    }
}
module.exports = {
    exported1 = handler(func1),
    exported2 = handler(func2)
}

exported1(args)
```

Comment: I need to clarify, this is for a module and I would prefer that you didn't need to call it with func1 and func2, but it would be passed on automatically.

Comment: But I'm still not clear what you're exactly looking for.

Comment: Probably just bad design by me, but func1 and func2 take some arguments, and return some values that handler passes into a class.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad at least it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get why to use this pattern, but I am sure there is more to the code and guess you could do the following:

```
function func1(args) {
    console.info(`func1 ${args}`);
}

function func2(args) {
    console.info(`func2 ${args}`);
}

function handler(func, args) {
    return func(args);
}

module.exports = {
    exported1: (args) => {
        return handler(func1, (args));
    },
    exported2: (args) => {
        return handler(func2, (args));
    },
};
```